how to avoid getting DeadSystemException from Battery Manager
I am running a loop every one second to get the Battery current of the device in a coroutine. But it give a DeadSystemException on some devices.
my code is
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (true) {
                currentNow = try {
                    batteryManager?.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW) ?: 1
                } catch (_: DeadSystemException) {
                    1
                }

                val curValue = limitDigits(currentNow)
                val cur = "$curValue mA"
                val cur1 = "$batteryCur : $cur"
                val power = (curValue.toInt() * batteryVoltage) / 1000000.0
                val powerDis = "%.2f".format(power) + " W"
                val powerDisTop = "$batteryPow : $powerDis"
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    txtBatteryCurrentDis.text = cur
                    txtBatteryCurrentTop.text = cur1
                    txtBatteryPowerDis.text = powerDis
                    txtBatteryPowerTop.text = powerDisTop
                }
                delay(1000)
            }
        }

private fun limitDigits(n: Int): String {
    val abs = abs(n)
    var tempValue = abs.toString()
    var absoluteValueFinal = abs
    try {
        absoluteValueFinal = if (isCharging) absoluteValueFinal else absoluteValueFinal * -1
        if (tempValue.length >= 6) {
            absoluteValueFinal /= 1000
            tempValue = abs(absoluteValueFinal).toString()
            if (tempValue.length >= 6) {
                absoluteValueFinal /= 1000
            }
        }

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
    return if (n != 0 && n != Int.MIN_VALUE && n != Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        if (isBatteryFull) {
            return "0"
        } else {
            absoluteValueFinal.toString()
        }
    } else {
        "0"
    }
}

The Exception I get in crashlytics is
Caused by: android.os.DeadSystemException: 
android.os.BatteryManager.queryProperty(BatteryManager.java:274)
android.os.BatteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.java:290)
com.ytheekshana.deviceinfo.fragments.TabBattery$onCreateView$2.invokeSuspend(TabBattery.kt:226)
kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:101)
kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.java:113)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:89)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java:589)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:823)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:720)
kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:707)

Can anyone point me how to fix this?

If you're actually running in a loop querying that every second, the biggest drain on the battery is probably your query code.  The charge doesn't change so rapidly that there's any reason to do that.

So whats your recommendation in obtaining battery current. I am displaying this data in a chart.

Reduce your polling by an order or two of magnitude.  There's not enough second to second change in usage to make that data valuable.  The only time it would be valuable is if you were measuring the usage during some operation.  And if you're doing that, a multimeter connected across the battery is FAR more accurate.

You can't avoid it. Any running app starts seeing DeadSystemException when the Android system is shutting down. Just ignore it.
